# Changing the Navigation Bar Hover Event

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

I have this new nav bar hover event that's in CSS but I can't figure out a way to switch it out with my current nav bar hover event.

My Current Nav Bar Code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- CSS -->
<link href="http://themodulesource.com/bootstrap3_for_enjin/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<style type="text/css">



/*Positioning of our logo*/
.navbar-brand img {
margin-right: 20px;
margin-left: 20px;

}


/*Non responsive hacks*/

.container .navbar-header,
.container .navbar-collapse {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}

/* Always float the navbar header */
.navbar-header {
  float: left;
}

.nav-container{
max-width: none !important;
width: 1025px;
}

.nav-container{
margin-left:1955px;
}

.navbar-static-top {
margin-left: -1953px !important;
width: 4000px !important;
position: fixed !important;
}

/*End Non-Responsive Hacks*/


/*START ENJIN BAR NAV POSITIONING*/

/*Our nested admin and profile menus*/




 #boot_admin a .caret, #boot_profile a .caret {
    border-top-color: rgb(153, 153, 153) !important;
    border-bottom-color: rgb(153, 153, 153) !important;
}


#boot_admin{
margin-top:0px;

}

#boot_admin a:nth-child(1){
display:none;
}

#boot_profile{
height:auto;
}



#boot_profile span:hover{
background-color: transparent;
color: rgb(51, 51, 51) !important;
text-decoration: none;
}



/*Changes the style of our entire dropdown box to mimick Boot strap style*/
.element_dropdown_menu.element_popup.enjinbar-menu{
margin-top:32px;
z-index:99999;
border-radius:0px !important;
border-color:white !important;
}

#boot_profile .element_username{
color: rgb(153,153,153) !important;
text-decoration:none !important;
}

#boot_profile .element_username:hover{
color:white !important;
}

/*Our inner elements of our entire enjin drop down*/
.element_popup .inner {
background-color: white !important;
text-decoration:none;
list-style:none;
border:none;
-webkit-background-clip:padding-box;
-moz-background-clip:padding;
background-clip:padding-box;
}

/*Text - Our inner elements of our entire enjin drop down*/
.element_popup .inner li a{
color:#333;
font-size:13px;
font-family:Arial;
padding:4px 10px !important;
}

/*Text - Hover - Our inner elements of our entire enjin drop down*/
.element_popup .inner .menu-link:hover{
text-decoration:none;
color:#ffffff;
background-color:#0081c2;
background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#0088cc), to(#0077b3));
background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, #0088cc, #0077b3);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff0088cc', endColorstr='#ff0077b3', GradientType=0);
}

/*Enjin Divider lines to look...better*/
.element_popup .inner .menu-divider-line{
background-color: #E5E5E5 !important;
border-bottom: 1px solid white !important;
height:1px !important;
opacity:0.4;
}

/*Profile drop down item hover events*/
.element_popup .inner .item:hover{
background-color: rgb(0, 129, 194);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(0, 136, 204), rgb(0, 119, 179));
}

/*Profile drop down text style*/
.element_popup .inner .item a{
text-decoration:none;
font-weight: normal;
margin-bottom:-2px; /*Reduces some spacing..since menu is huge*/
color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
font-family:arial;
}

/*Profile drop down text style - hover*/
.element_popup .inner .item a:hover{
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

/*Font,text - Our site box at bottom of profile dropdown*/
.sitebox a {
font-size:15px !important;
color:#333;
margin-left:-10px;
margin-top:-16px;
background-color:transparent;
}

/*Font,text, make less default space - Our site box at bottom of profile dropdown*/
.enjinbar-menu-user .sitebox{
margin-bottom:15px;
}

/*That damn gear! - Our site box at bottom of profile dropdown*/
.enjinbar-menu-user .sitebox .gear {
background-position: 40px 0px; /*Removes Enjin's mysterious extra icons*/ }

/*Text for site urls - Our site box at bottom of profile dropdown*/
.sitebox .url{
color:#333;
}



/*Removes our likes etc.*/
#enjin-bar #enjin-bar-likes{
display:none !important;
}

/*Removes site info,site name and our admin gear*/
#enjin-bar .left a:nth-of-type(1),#enjin-bar .left a:nth-of-type(2),#enjin-bar .left a:nth-of-type(3){
display:none !important;
}

/*creates a default right position for our admin, fixed, position manually on your fixed nav*/
#enjin-bar .left{
margin-top:8px;
z-index:9999;
margin-left:530px;
position:fixed;
}

/*Our admin text*/
#enjin-bar .left a{
color: rgb(119, 119, 119);
font-size:13px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size:13px;
font-family:Arial;
text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

/*Our admin text on hover*/
#enjin-bar .left a:hover{
color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
text-decoration:none;
}

/*Makes navbar links shade on hover*/
.navbar .nav>li:hover{background-color:#C2C2C2;
box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125) inset; /*fancy inset shadow, feel free to remove*/
}

/*Colors the background of the dropdown*/
.dropdown-menu {
background-color: #ffffff;
}

/*END Enjin bar nav positioning*/




</style>

</head>

<body>



<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="nav-container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://mineflow.us">Mineflow</a>
        </div>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="http://www.mineflow.us/home"><i class="icon-home"></i>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.mineflow.us/forum""><i class="icon-pencil"></i>Forum</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.mineflow.us/shop""><i class="icon-book">
</i>Donate</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.mineflow.us/vote""><i class="icon-star">
</i>Vote</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://mineflow.us/status""><i class="icon-signal">
</i>Status</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
           <a href="http://www.mineflow.us/members" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="200" data-close-others="false"><i class="icon-globe"></i>Members<b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="http://www.mineflow.us/members"">All Members</a></li>
                      <li><a href="http://www.mineflow.us/staff"">Staff</a></li>

</li>
              </ul>
</ul><!--End pull left nav-->
<ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right"><!--start pull right nav-->
<li id="boot_admin"></li>
<li id="boot_profile"></li>
<li id="boot_join"></li>
<li id="boot_login"></li>
<li id="boot_register"></li>
          </ul>

      </div>
    </div>






<!-- Le javascript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="http://themodulesource.com/bootstrap3_for_enjin/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://themodulesource.com/bootstrap3_for_enjin/hover_js/twitter-bootstrap-hover-dropdown.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#enjin-bar .left a[href$="/admin"]').appendTo($('#boot_admin'));
    $('#enjin-bar .right .user a').appendTo($('#boot_profile'));
    $('<b class="caret"></b>"]').appendTo($('#boot_admin a'));
    $('<b class="caret"></b>').appendTo($('#boot_profile a'));
    $('.navbar-static-top').prependTo($('#page'));
    $('#enjin-bar a[href$="/login"]').appendTo($('#boot_login'));
    $('#enjin-bar a[href$="/register"]').appendTo($('#boot_register'));
    $('#enjin-bar .right .join-site a').appendTo($('#boot_join'));



});
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

This is the CSS that I would like for the hover event to become.

```
<style>
                  <!--@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700);#cssmenu {
background:#FFF;
width:auto;
line-height:1;
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
font-family:'PT Sans', sans-serif;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#cssmenu ul {
list-style:none;
display:block;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#cssmenu ul:after {
content:' ';
display:block;
font-size:0;
height:0;
clear:both;
visibility:hidden;
}

#cssmenu ul li {
display:block;
position:relative;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#cssmenu ul li a {
text-decoration:none;
display:block;
-webkit-transition:color .2s ease;
-moz-transition:color .2s ease;
-ms-transition:color .2s ease;
-o-transition:color .2s ease;
transition:color .2s ease;
margin:0;
}

#cssmenu ul li ul {
position:absolute;
left:-9999px;
top:auto;
}

#cssmenu ul li ul li {
max-height:0;
position:absolute;
-webkit-transition:max-height .4s ease-out;
-moz-transition:max-height .4s ease-out;
-ms-transition:max-height .4s ease-out;
-o-transition:max-height .4s ease-out;
transition:max-height .4s ease-out;
background:#2E2E2E;
}

#cssmenu ul li ul li.has-sub:after {
display:block;
position:absolute;
content:'';
height:10px;
width:10px;
border-radius:5px;
background:#000;
z-index:1;
top:13px;
right:15px;
}

#cssmenu ul li ul li.has-sub:before {
display:block;
position:absolute;
content:'';
height:0;
width:0;
border:3px solid transparent;
border-left-color:#fff;
z-index:2;
top:15px;
right:15px;
}

#cssmenu ul li ul li a {
font-size:14px;
font-weight:400;
text-transform:none;
color:#000;
letter-spacing:0;
display:block;
width:140px;
padding:11px 10px 11px 20px;
}

#cssmenu ul li ul li:hover > a,#cssmenu ul li ul li.active > a {
color:#4cb6ea;
}

#cssmenu ul li ul li:hover:after,#cssmenu ul li ul li.active:after {
background:#4cb6ea;
}

function status() {
    $('#update').html("<img src='http://i.imgur.com/5DGm7WZ.gif'>");
    setInterval(function(){var status=new XMLHttpRequest();status.open("GET","http://minecraft-api.com/v1/get/?server=69.175.70.162",true);
    status.onreadystatechange=function(){if(status.readyState==4){mineplex=JSON.parse(status.responseText);if(mineplex.status){
    $('#update').html(mineplex.players.online);}else{$('#update').html(mineplex.players.online);}}};status.send();},1000);
}

#cssmenu ul li ul li:hover > ul {
left:170px;
top:0;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li {
float:left;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li:after {
content:'';
display:block;
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:0;
top:0;
z-index:0;
background:#2E2E2E;
-webkit-transition:height .2s;
-moz-transition:height .2s;
-ms-transition:height .2s;
-o-transition:height .2s;
transition:height .2s;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
padding-right:40px;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
display:block;
content:'';
background:#fff;
height:12px;
width:12px;
position:absolute;
border-radius:13px;
right:14px;
top:16px;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
display:block;
content:'';
border:4px solid transparent;
border-top-color:#4cb6ea;
z-index:2;
height:0;
width:0;
position:absolute;
right:16px;
top:21px;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
color:#fff;
font-weight:700;
letter-spacing:1px;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-size:14px;
z-index:2;
position:relative;
padding:15px 20px;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li:hover:after,#cssmenu > ul > li.active:after {
height:100%;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
color:#000;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a:after,#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a:after {
background:#000;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a:before,#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a:before {
border-top-color:#fff;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul {
left:0;
}

#cssmenu #menu-button {
display:none;
}

#cssmenu ul li ul li:hover > ul > li,#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul > li {
max-height:72px;
position:relative;
}

@media all and max-width 768px,only screen and -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio 2 and max-width 1024px,only screen and min--moz-device-pixel-ratio 2 and max-width 1024px,only screen and -o-min-device-pixel-ratio 21 and max-width 1024px,only screen and min-device-pixel-ratio 2 and max-width 1024px,only screen and min-resolution 192dpi and max-width 1024px,only screen and min-resolution 2dppx and max-width 1024px{
#cssmenu > ul {
max-height:0;
overflow:hidden;
-webkit-transition:max-height .35s ease-out;
-moz-transition:max-height .35s ease-out;
-ms-transition:max-height .35s ease-out;
-o-transition:max-height .35s ease-out;
transition:max-height .35s ease-out;
}

#cssmenu > ul.open {
max-height:1000px;
border-top:1px solid rgba(110,110,110,0.25);
}

#cssmenu ul {
width:100%;
}

#cssmenu ul > li {
float:none;
}

#cssmenu ul li a {
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
box-sizing:border-box;
width:100%;
padding:12px 20px;
}

#cssmenu ul li ul,#cssmenu ul li ul li ul,#cssmenu ul li ul li:hover > ul {
left:0;
position:relative;
}

#cssmenu ul li ul li,#cssmenu ul li:hover > ul > li {
max-height:999px;
position:relative;
background:none;
}

#cssmenu ul li ul li a {
color:#fff;
width:auto;
padding:8px 20px 8px 35px;
}

#cssmenu ul li ul ul li a {
padding:8px 20px 8px 50px;
}

#cssmenu ul li ul li:hover > a {
color:#000;
}

#cssmenu #menu-button {
display:block;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
box-sizing:border-box;
width:100%;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-weight:700;
font-size:14px;
letter-spacing:1px;
color:#fff;
cursor:pointer;
padding:15px 20px;
}

#cssmenu #menu-button:after {
display:block;
content:'';
position:absolute;
height:3px;
width:22px;
border-top:2px solid #fff;
border-bottom:2px solid #fff;
right:20px;
top:16px;
}

#cssmenu #menu-button:before {
display:block;
content:'';
position:absolute;
height:3px;
width:22px;
border-top:2px solid #fff;
right:20px;
top:26px;
}

#cssmenu ul > li:after,#cssmenu ul li.has-sub > a:after,#cssmenu ul li.has-sub > a:before,#cssmenu ul li ul li.has-sub:after,#cssmenu ul li ul li.has-sub:before {
display:none;
}
}
               </style>
```

Is there a way I can do this? I've tried many times but failed every time....
Can someone help? Also, if you're wondering why I'm trying to do this... it's because the CSS adds a cool effect when you hover over it instead of it just being highlighted with out any effect/animation.

Comment: can you please set up a working fiddle with your code?

Comment: That's not enough code for a navbar, you should post the entire code of every single page that uses the navbar. Seriously, you couldn't narrow it down to a readable example ?

Answer (score 0):

Code for you to test - HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="divOneTest" onmouseover="this.id='divTwoTest';" onmouseout="this.id='divOneTest';">
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS (make a new css file called css.css)

```
#divOneTest{
border-style: outset;
border-width: 2px;
border-color: black;
}

#divTwoTest{
border-style: outset;
border-width: 2px;
border-color: white;
background-color: black;
}
```

Does that help?

Comment: So... what do you mean?
Sorry I'm kinda new to CSS and HTML.

Comment: Well you should really have a separate CSS file for your CSS code, rather than putting it within your HTML page. Then differentiate between the CSS' by using classes or id's (i've used id's). 

That's a lot of code there for someone who's new to HTML and CSS. I'll update my answer so you can test it and see what to do, and then you can add the functionality to your much more complex code once you understand how it works.

Comment: I still really don't get it... :(
Sorry if this is annoying but as I said I'm really new to HTML and CSS.
Maybe this'll help. If you would like to see the nav bar design then go to mineflow.us
If you would like to see a navbar with the hover event. Then please go to this website mineflow.us/hitest
I hope this helps.

Comment: I made a Jsfiddle with it and the result was a super thin black bar that when you hover over it, it just changed colors...
Not that helpfull...
Anymore suggestions?